# Magento 2-Override FinalPriceBox using Preference or Plugin class of Configurable Product module

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price, plugin, preference

Anyone has idea how to make preference or plugin on `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox` class of `Magento\ConfigurableProduct`.

Basically, new function i wanted to add in the FinalPriceBox class and to use new function in `final_price.phtml` file.

I see code in the `di.xml` of `module-configurableproduct` module. But do not know how to use in new custom module?

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="priceResolver" xsi:type="object">ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="priceResolver" xsi:type="object">ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Mean using `di.xml` magento is changing   **priceResolver**  parameter value of `Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice` from  `PriceResolverInterface $priceResolver` to  `ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver $priceResolve`

So,You will use `preference` to add a method then you have to use below code at di.xml

> ```
> <type name="{YournewRwriteClass}">
>     <arguments>
>         <argument name="priceResolver" xsi:type="object">ConfigurableFinalPriceResolver</argument>
>     </arguments>
> </type>
> ```